# How to create an instance of a class by passing the type

Tags: kotlin

I want to be able to say make an instance of this class and give a type then the code can instantiate a new instance of that class.

```
fun maker(type: Class<Animal>): Animal {
    if(type == Class<Dog>) {
       return Dog()
    } 
    else if (type == Class<Cat>) {}
    ...
}
```

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just use `Class.newInstance()`?

Answer (score 2):

If they all have zero-argument constructors, you can do:

```
fun maker(type: Class<Animal>): Animal {
    return type.newInstance()
}
```

You can make it return the type that was passed in for a little more versatility:

```
fun <T: Animal> maker(type: Class<T>): T {
    return type.newInstance()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct version following your example (not sure if best approach overall):

```
fun <T: Animal> maker(type: Class<T>): T? {
    return when (type) {
      Cat::class.java -> Cat() as T
      Dog::class.java -> Dog() as T
      else -> null
    }
}
```

And then to create objects:

```
val a = maker(Cat::class.java)
val b = maker(Dog::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Updated) I am not an expert in Kotlin but you can do something like this :

```
import kotlin.reflect.KClass
import kotlin.reflect.full.createInstance

class A {
    fun greet() {
        println("Hello A");
    }
}

class B{
    fun greet() {
        println("Hello B");
    }
}

fun <T : Any> maker(clazz: KClass<T>): T {
    return clazz.createInstance();
}

val aObj = maker<A>(A::class);
aObj.greet();

val bObj = maker<B>(B::class);
bObj.greet();
```

Output:

```
Hello A
Hello B
```

I hope now it makes sense you just need to pass the class to the method and it returns an object.

As you will be using Animal as a parent class so you can replace Any => Animal

```
fun <T : Animal> maker(clazz: KClass<T>): T {
    return clazz.createInstance();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  [`objectInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/object-instance.html) doesn't create a new instance; it returns the existing single instance if the type is an object, or otherwise (as in this case) null.

Comment: It's redundant to make the type reified and also take a KClass parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If the function can be `inline` you can also use [reified](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) type

```
inline fun<reified T: Animal> make() = T::class.createInstance()

...

val dog = make<Dog>()
```

Please notice that to use `createInstance()` the class must have no-arg constructor or `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown